# Book about superpower academy

Tags: story-identification

I read some book about a boy had superpowers and he met a man who had same powers as him (I can't really remember the power but I think it was to control things). Then he went up a mountain with a singer who had the same powers as him too and he was inviting him to his group so they can do something bad but he declined.

Then he goes to some school for superpowers and one of his friend is really good at carving. So they learn their superpowers. Then he finds out his mum is in danger because some people put something in her or something so she runs away to keep him safe thinking she is bad. Then he goes to find her and sees his dad trying to comfort her then the ground swallow his parents and he has a fight with  the bad people.

There was also some people without powers like the president or something and he helped the boy. Then some sacred guy comes out and the main characters parents are actually alive.

There was also some part somewhere where they move somewhere. And before he met the good man he heard a deer crying and found the good man helping the deer.